# Scroll bar is attaching wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to attach a `ScrollBar` to a `ListBox` but I don't know what I did wrong in the below code.

```
class Form:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.frame = Frame(self.root)

        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.frame)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')

        self.listBoxDeTrimis = Listbox(self.frame)
        self.listBoxDeTrimis.pack()
        for i in range(100):
            self.listBoxDeTrimis.insert(END, i)
        self.listBoxDeTrimis.place(relx=0.47, rely=0.1)
        self.listBoxDeTrimis.config(height=15, width=30, yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.scrollbar.config(command=self.listBoxDeTrimis.yview)
```

The scroll bar attaches to the `root` and I want to set it where is that yellow line, for the `ListBox`

[image]

Comment: You need a `Frame` which holds the `Scrollbar`and the `Listbox`. You can do: `class Form(tk.Frame):` and `Scrollbar(self)`.

Comment: I tried with a frame, but the ListBox dissapeared

Comment: You don't layout the `self.frame` widget, also i recommend to use `.pack(side='left'` to layout the `Listbox`

Comment: You have called both `.pack()` and `.place(...)` on the listbox.  Just use `.pack(fill='both', expand=1, side='left')`

Comment: Done. Thank you. I have layout the frame and now it works